# IBM x3550 BIOS not installed?

Tags: bios, ibm

Whenever I boot to the Configuration/Setup Utility it always shows "BIOS not installed!", even though my startup screen shows that I'm running the latest 3550 bios (1.17)...

Is this something to worry about? Not finding any other errors with it or experiencing any problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the adapter BIOSes, saying that this adapter does not have boot devices assigned to it, and so adapter BIOS has no reason to be loaded.